# Implement Basic HttpClient Post with Loopj on Android

Tags: android, httpclient, android-async-http, loopj, asynchttpclient

I am new to Android programming and am having some difficulty implementing a basic version of a message sender using the Loopj library.

Here is my code:

```
package com.test.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

import org.apache.http.Header;

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("https://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[]     response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
           }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                //called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This code gives me two errors I am trying to work through:

1. The line AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(); underlines AsyncHttpClient and reports and error: "Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method for onFailure"
2. The @Override designation for onSuccess and onFailure is underlined and the error states "The method does not override the method from its superclass".

How can I make this work in my Android Activity?

Comment: why you use this old http client without community and updates?

Comment: Well because Im new, and I see example code that pushes messages to Azure using this code. Do you have any suggestions? Im open to different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of wrong imports.

You should replace:

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
```

with

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
```

**UPDATE:**

BTW if you want to make HTTP POST you should use `.post()` instead of `.get()`

Comment: This works, please suggest alternative libraries if you know of any.

Comment: If you want just client okhttp is the best library for that now.
If you want REST API client retrofit2 with okhttp and rxjava is most modern stack.
IMHO

Comment: Thanks for your help, Im going to try to adapt the old code to okhttp.